# Difference between cocos2d-android and cocos2d-android-1

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

Can anybody please explain me what is the difference between cocos2d-android and cocos2d-android-1? What are the functionalities differ between them? And the related details.. I was searching, but not yet get anything appropriate to it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main difference is that [cocos2d-android](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android/) is basically dead, or at least [it has had no activity since November 16, 2010](http://feed://code.google.com/feeds/p/cocos2d-android/svnchanges/basic).

The [cocos2d-android-1](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android-1/) branch was created because of a lack of activity in the cocos2d-android version. The [code is hosted on github](https://github.com/ZhouWeikuan/cocos2d) and the commit log shows at least a few commits per months. It's not as frequently updated as one would hope it to be, but it's better than nothing.

Unfortunately both versions are still based on cocos2d-iphone 0.99.4 which was released in July 2010. So if you absolutely want to develop Android apps in Java, use cocos2d-android-1. If Java is not a deciding factor for you, then [cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org) (C++) will be the better choice since it is frequently updated and has financial backing.

Comment: Thanks for the appropriate reply.. Basically I am a java developer.. So I need to go with cocos2d-android-1..